# Number of sampling and expected value of 3rd-best draw

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, order-statistics

Suppose $n>m$.

Person 1 samples $n$ times (i.i.d.)

Person 2 samples $m$ times (i.i.d.)

$x_{(n-2)}$ is the 3rd-highest number obtained from $n$ sampling
from distribution $F$

$y_{(m-2)}$ is the 3rd-highest number obtained from $m$ sampling
from distribution $F$

Question: Conditional upon the largest number is the same from both
people, is the expected value of 3rd-best number of person 1 bigger
than the expected value of 3rd-best number of person 2?

That is,

$$E(x_{(n-2)}-y_{(m-2)}|x_{(n)}=y_{(m)})>0  ?? $$

I guess this ``condition'' part is irrelevant because it's i.i.d.
sampling. (correct?)

Then the problem reduces to

$$E(x_{(n-2)}-y_{(m-2)})>0 ??$$

This should be intuitively true. But should there be some regularity
conditions imposed on $F$ to make this hold with "strict" inequality?

Comment: I'm not sure that the condition is irrelevant. First of all, it has nothing to do with the fact that each sampling is of i.i.d. r.v., since $X_{(n-2)}$ and $X_{(n)}$ are not independent (same for $Y$); at most, it would have to do with the (not explicitly stated) fact that each $X_i$ is independent from each $Y_j$. And given that $E\left(X_{(n)}\right)>E\left(Y_{(m)}\right)$, I'm not sure that the condition is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, I would say the condition is relevant. As I put in a comment, first of all, were it not relevant, this would have nothing to do with the fact that each sampling is of i.i.d. r.v., since $X_{(n-2)}$ and $X_{(n)}$ are not independent (same for $Y_{(m-2)}$ and $Y_{(m)}$); at most, it would have to do with the (not explicitly stated) fact that each $X_i$ is independent from each $Y_j$.

Even more, given that $E\left(X_{(n)}\right)>E\left(Y_{(m)}\right)$, this seems to impose a condition.

Supose that the condition were $X_{(n)}=Y_{(m-3)}$, if you use the same reasoning you would conclude that this fact does not affect the sign of $E(X_{(n-2)}-Y_{(m-2)})$ while, in fact, is saying that for sure $X_{(n-2)}\le Y_{(m-2)}$ and so
$$E\big(X_{(n-2)}-Y_{(m-2)}|X_{(n)}=Y_{(m-3)}\big)\le 0.$$

Try again not dismissing the condition. Intuition says to me that anyway the answer is affirmative.

Let's assume that both samples from the same distribution verify $x_{(n)}=y_{(m)}=K\in \mathbb R$, and for the sake of simplicity let's suppose that the distribution has support on $(0,+\infty)$, you have $n-1$ observations to accommodate in the interval $(0,K)$, and then another (fewer) $m-1$ observations to accommodate in the same interval. In the extreme case that $n>>m$ it is to be expected that $X_{(n-1)}>Y_{(m-1)}$ with great probability, and perhaps also that $X_{(n-2)}>Y_{(m-2)}$ (imagine, for instance, that $n=10$ or $n=100$, and that $m=3$ or that $m=4$).

I can't say this reasoning works over and over since $n-k$ eventually becomes small, although still $m-k$ is even smaller and eventually becomes $1$, but I guess is fine for $k=2$ (of course, this is not even close to a formal proof).